# Is it Possible to Have a Tropical Climate With a Summer Dry Season?

Tags: internal-consistency, climate, geography, weather, seasons

In my book series, the northern coast of one of my provinces is in the tropics and on the western side of its continent. However, because it is mountainous and on a relatively cold sea, I was thinking of having a tropical climate, but with a rainfall pattern much more similar to an exaggerated version of a Mediterranean climate (basically what would happen if the South Asian Monsoon arrived at the opposite time of year). Is this feasible to do at all, and if so what should I change to make this more realistic?

Comment: Without seeing a map of the area including sea currents and the basics of your planet (distance from the sun, tilt, etc.) I can't see any reason why this wouldn't be feasible. [Tropical climates have summer dry seasons](https://www.climatetypesforkids.com/tropical-wet-and-dry-climate). However, it depends on what you mean by "tropical." The climatological definition is at odds with the Dagobah System definition, which is what most people think "tropical" means.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can easily have the monsoon arrive at the opposite time of the year: simply decide to celebrate New Year's Day on July 1st. January 1st is the first day of the year by historical accident; maybe the Roman senate, when they decided to rename Quinctilis to July in honor of a certain dictator of the Julian clan, also decided to move the official beginning of the year.

Comment: Can you explain how your tropical sea is 'relatively cold'? You say Mediterranean climate, but that is not Tropical (Köppen group A), it is Temperate (Köppen group C). VTC'd for lack of necessary details.

Comment: @rek It's on two seas: one to the southwest that's cold due to upwelling near the coast and one to the north that's tropical and very warm